# White Background in Data Augmention - CNN

Tags: matplotlib, conv-neural-network

I have written a code for data augmention. But the images are shown in white. Everywhere is white so i cant see the images augmented. The code is below. Can you help me to fix it precisely? Cuz it pissed me off:/

thanks in advance.

The code:

```
# Data Augmention with ImageDataGenerator
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center = False, 
    samplewise_center = False,  
    featurewise_std_normalization = False, 
    samplewise_std_normalization = False,  
    zca_whitening = False, 
    rotation_range = 30, 
    zoom_range = 0.2,
    width_shift_range = 0.2, 
    height_shift_range = 0.2,
    horizontal_flip = True, 
    vertical_flip = True) 

datagen.fit(x_train)

# Display
from matplotlib import pyplot
for X_batch, y_batch in datagen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size = 9):
    for i in range(0,9): # 3x3 görsellerden oluşan bir ızgara oluşturalım.
        pyplot.subplot(330 + 1 + i)
        pyplot.imshow(X_batch[i].reshape(224, 224, 3))
    pyplot.show()
    break
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6GVn.png)

I am writing a PhD thesis on computational archival science. Using some deep learning techniques with satellite images to classification. But i've got an error and deadlocked..